# Type X is not assignable to type 'TaskDataState'. in redux conversion to typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

I am trying to convert my redux reducer to typescript, but I get the following error when I create an interface for my initial state. [image: Error that typescript throws]

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-tom-t9g969?file=/src/reduxfile.ts

Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `taskPage` property is `TaskPage` whose properties are all `required`, but you assign an empty object `{}` to `taskPage`. That's why you got the error. You need to declare these properties and assign an initial value.

Besides, the `currentWorkspace` and `currentTeam` properties have the same issue. If you don't want to assign initial values to them, you can declare their type to accept `undefined` type.

```
export interface TaskDataState {
    access: Access | boolean;
    error: boolean;
    status: string;
    priority: string | null;
    taskPage: TaskPage;
    taskList: Task[];
    workspaces: Workspace[];
    // currentWorkspace: CurrentWorkspace;
    currentWorkspace: CurrentWorkspace | undefined;
    // currentTeam: Team;
    currentTeam: Team | undefined;
    prevWorkspaceUrl: string;
    labels: string[];
}
```

```
import {
    SET_TASKLIST,
    SET_TASK,
    DELETE_ALL_TASKS,
    GET_TASKS_ERROR,
    SET_WORKSPACE,
    GET_WORKSPACE_SUCCESS,
    GET_WORKSPACE_FAILURE,
    SET_CURRENTTEAM,
    GET_TEAM_FAILURE,
    GET_TEAM_SUCCESS,
    SET_ACCESS_ID,
    SET_STATUS,
    SET_PRIORITY,
    SET_LABELS,
} from "./actions";
//

export interface TaskDataState {
    access: Access | boolean;
    error: boolean;
    status: string;
    priority: string | null;
    taskPage: TaskPage;
    taskList: Task[];
    workspaces: Workspace[];
    currentWorkspace: CurrentWorkspace;
    currentTeam: Team;
    prevWorkspaceUrl: string;
    labels: string[];
}

export interface CurrentWorkspace {
    companySize: number;
    name: string;
    teams: Team[];
    url: string;
    users: string[];
    _id: string;
    error: boolean;
    priority: string;
    status: string;
}

export interface Team {
    identifier: string;
    name: string;
    tasks: Task[];
    workspace: string;
    _id: string;
}

export interface Workspace {
    companySize: number;
    name: string;
    teams: string[];
    url: string;
    users: string[];
    _id: string;
}

export interface Access {
    status: boolean;
    id: string;
}

export interface TaskPage {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    team: string;
    status: string;
    priority: string;
    labels: string[];
    description: string;
}

export interface Task {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    team: string;
    description: string;
    status: string;
    priority: string | null;
    labels: string[];
}

//

const initialState: TaskDataState = {
    taskList: [],
    taskPage: {
        _id: "",
        title: "",
        team: "",
        status: "",
        priority: "",
        labels: [],
        description: "",
    },
    workspaces: [],
    currentWorkspace: undefined,
    currentTeam: undefined,
    prevWorkspaceUrl: "",
    access: false,
    error: false,
    status: "Todo",
    priority: "",
    labels: [],
};

const taskDataReducer = (state = initialState, action): TaskDataState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_TASKLIST:
            return {
                ...state,
                taskList: action.payload,
            };
        case SET_STATUS:
            return {
                ...state,
                status: action.payload,
            };
        case SET_PRIORITY:
            return {
                ...state,
                priority: action.payload,
            };
        case SET_LABELS:
            return {
                ...state,
                labels: action.payload,
            };
        case DELETE_ALL_TASKS:
            return {
                ...state,
                taskList: [],
            };
        case SET_TASK:
            return {
                ...state,
                taskPage: action.payload,
            };
        case GET_TASKS_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: true,
            };
        case SET_WORKSPACE:
            return {
                ...state,
                workspaces: action.payload,
            };
        case GET_WORKSPACE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
                currentWorkspace: action.payload,
            };
        case GET_WORKSPACE_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                access: false,
                error: true,
            };
        case SET_CURRENTTEAM:
            return {
                ...state,
                currentTeam: action.payload,
            };
        case GET_TEAM_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                error: false,
            };
        case GET_TEAM_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                access: false,
                error: true,
            };
        case SET_ACCESS_ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                access: {
                    status: true,
                    id: action.payload,
                },
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default taskDataReducer;
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-77055904-g5wmnf?file=/src/reduxfile.ts:404-412)